# Gridview horizontal spacing between items not working

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm creating a gridview in android that has 3 columns and horizontal spacing of 10dp.. Everything works fine in Android Lolipop, But when I try on Kitkat the spacing doesn't work as expected.

Here is the problem:

[image]

There is no horizontal spacing between items.. Here is my xml:

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
```